# How To Write Test case for Java Interface which extends Java frame work interface

Tags: java, unit-testing, interface

I have a interface where my interface extends the spring PagingAndSortingRepository. I want to write unit test case. How can I write unit test case for this.

```
public interface LookUpRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Lookup, Long> {

    public List<Lookup> findAll();
}
```

can some body help .........

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Save some entities by repo and then check if you findAll method is returning all entities which you saved.

Comment: What is the issue? Just write a test for your implementing class!

Comment: @kism3t there is no implemented class, Every thing taken care by spring frame work.

Comment: @Sasidhar this is important information that should be added to your question.

Answer (score 0):

So because this class is an interface, it doesn't have any internal logic. As a result, it doesn't really make sense to unit test it. Instead, you should unit test the implementations of the interface.

A pattern which I have seen is to define a set of unit tests on the interface and then extend that unit test for each implementation. This makes sure that the implementations all adhere to the interface.

```
public abstract class LookUpRepositoryTest {

  public abstract LookUpRepository getRepository();

  // ... your tests ...
}

public MyLookUpRepositoryTest extends LookUpRepositoryTest {

  @Override
  public LookUpRepository getRepository() {
     return new MyLookUpRepository();
  }

}
```

As I'm looking at your code, it appears to be using Spring data. If this is the case, you will need to look at Spring unit testing.